# Tailwindcss / Vite / Vue - Using #{!important} - results in [vite] Internal server error: [postcss] Unknown word or with '!w-3' [vite] expected ";"

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css, vite

dev dependencies

```
{
  "vue": "^3.2.45",
  "vite": "^4.0.3",
  "sass": "^1.57.1",
  "postcss": "^8.4.19",
  "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
}
```

Vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig, type PluginOption } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import eslintPlugin from 'vite-plugin-eslint'
import { visualizer } from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer'

import type { UserConfig as VitestUserConfigInterface } from "vitest/config"
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'
import { resolve } from 'path'

const vitestConfig: VitestUserConfigInterface = {
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
  },
}

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    target: ['edge90', 'chrome90', 'firefox90', 'safari15'],
    outDir: './dist',
    lib: {
      formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
      entry: resolve(__dirname, './src/components/index.ts'),
      name: 'Vuesty',
      fileName: 'index',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue'],
      output: { globals: { vue: 'Vue' } },
    },
  },
  test: vitestConfig.test,
  plugins: [vue(), eslintPlugin(),
    dts({
      beforeWriteFile: (filePath, content) => {
        const newFilePath = filePath
          .replace('/src', '/global');

        return {
          filePath: newFilePath,
          content,
        };
      },
      skipDiagnostics: true,
    }),
    visualizer({
      emitFile: true
    }) as PluginOption
  ],
})
```

avatar.scss

```
.v-avatar__status-circle_large{
  @apply  !w-2.5 ;
}
```

Avatar.vue

```
<style lang="scss">
@import "src/assets/themes/main/components/avatar.scss";
</style>
```

If i use global styles, not importing it directly into component then it works fine, but i need it exactly in the component

If the code is:

```
.v-avatar__status-circle_large{
  @apply !w-2.5 ;
}
```

Then error is: [vite] Internal server error: [sass] expected ";".

And if the code is:

```
.v-avatar__status-circle_large{
  @apply  w-2.5 #{!important};
}
```

Error:[vite] Internal server error  The `important` class does not exist. If `important` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.

Comment: Did you try @layer components https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-css-and-layer